# Blog Site in Anonymous Use in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio, .net

Trying to setup anonymous access to a SharePoint 2010 blog following:
http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/12/22/blog-site-in-anonymous-use/

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the source code is (VS 2012 C# 3.5):
[Source Code for Anonymous Access](http://sdrv.ms/YcIN49)

I have already enabled anonymous authentication on the site and toggled it off and on as well. Deployed and installed the solution and the feature was activated as well. Even did an iisreset just to be sure.

I can get to the main page of the blog but when navigating to the direct link (Example):
http://example.com/OA/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8

The authentication dialog displays.

Not sure what is wrong with the code but so far it will not allow anonymous access.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project download on my blog post that will give you working code.  http://www.townofbedrock.com/blog/?p=236

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: Will have to compare the codes from both to see where something went wrong but now in another project so will be some time before I can get to it.